# SharePoint Designer simple reminder

Tags: sharepoint, workflow, sharepoint-designer

do you have any idea why this workflow is producing errors?
When i click on "Check for Errors" nothing happens.
The popup in the screenshot comes in when i try to publish the workflow.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JSPrW.png)

The "if condition" is to check if the checkbox for the reminder is set.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is your `1 day`?

Comment: reminder is a choice field displayed as checkboxes (multipe selections allowed "1 day", "1 week", "1 month") and if the checkbox "1 day" is selected then send a mail 1 day before due date to a person.

Comment: Try _Log To History List_ the value of **Reminder** and run multiple tests to see what the actual values are when they are selected in different scenarios.